# Deep learning model is training on very less data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a deep learning model on 100000 rows with 80% of the training data and 20% of test data. The data is splitting however my model is showing the output of training with 2242. Below is the training code with model and output given. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Training Code:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tweet_table = cleaning_table(tweet_table)

def tokenization_tweets(dataset, features):
    tokenization = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=features)
    tokenization.fit(dataset)
    dataset_transformed = tokenization.transform(dataset).toarray()
    return dataset_transformed
    
 
def splitting(table):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(table.tweet, table.test, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tweet_table['test'] = tweet_table['Overall_Sentiment'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Positive' else (0 if x == 'Negative' else 2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = splitting(tweet_table)

#print(tweet_table["test"].value_counts())
#print(tweet_table["Overall_Sentiment"].value_counts())
#print(list(set(y_train)))
#print(list(set(y_test)))


#Create a Neural Network
#Create the model
def train(X_train_mod, y_train, features, shuffle, drop, layer1, layer2, epoch, lr, epsilon, validation):
    model_nn = Sequential()
    model_nn.add(Dense(layer1, input_shape=(features,), activation='relu'))
    model_nn.add(Dropout(drop))
    model_nn.add(Dense(layer2, activation='sigmoid'))
    model_nn.add(Dropout(drop))
    model_nn.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=epsilon, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
    model_nn.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                 optimizer=optimizer,
                 metrics=['accuracy'])
    model_nn.fit(np.array(X_train_mod), y_train,
                 batch_size=32,
                 epochs=epoch,
                 verbose=1,
                 validation_split=validation,
                 shuffle=shuffle)
    return model_nn


def test(X_test, model_nn):
    prediction = model_nn.predict(X_test)
    return prediction


def model1(X_train, y_train):   
    features = 3500
    shuffle = True
    drop = 0.5
    layer1 = 512
    layer2 = 256
    epoch = 5
    lr = 0.001
    epsilon = None
    validation = 0.1
    X_train_mod = tokenization_tweets(X_train, features)
    model = train(X_train_mod, y_train, features, shuffle, drop, layer1, layer2, epoch, lr, epsilon, validation)
    return model;

#model1(X_train, y_train)

#model11(X_train, y_train)

def save_model(model):
        # lets assume `model` is main model 
        model_json = model.to_json()
        with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(model_json, json_file)

        model.save_weights("model_weights.h5")

#print(len(X_train))
#print(len(y_train))
model_final = model1(X_train, y_train)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
2242/2242 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3426 - accuracy: 0.8476 - val_loss: 0.2690 - val_accuracy: 0.8857
Epoch 2/5
2242/2242 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2399 - accuracy: 0.9015 - val_loss: 0.2471 - val_accuracy: 0.8991
Epoch 3/5
2242/2242 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1912 - accuracy: 0.9205 - val_loss: 0.2447 - val_accuracy: 0.9028
Epoch 4/5
2242/2242 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1454 - accuracy: 0.9399 - val_loss: 0.2547 - val_accuracy: 0.9083
Epoch 5/5
2242/2242 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1046 - accuracy: 0.9552 - val_loss: 0.2874 - val_accuracy: 0.9084
--- 192.1562056541443 seconds ---
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Those are [batches](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit). and not *rows*.As you have passed `batch_size=32`

Comment: Thanks @skrrrt for replying. kindly share on how to train on all the 80000 rows separately and show with the output. thanks again for the help